# Segmentation Fault in char pointer

Tags: c, string-literals

I am getting segmentation fault when running the below code. What could be the reason for this error? Please help

```
int main()
{
    char *str2 = "Hello";
    str2[3] = 'J';
    printf("%s\n",str2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: String constants are immutable. Try `char str2[] = "Hello";`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a **undefined behaviour** because you are trying to modify the content of a [string literal](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/string_literal). A string literal mainly stored in a **read only location**. so you do not modify it, otherwise it is invoked undefined behaviour.

**C11 §6.4.5 String literals(Paragraph 7):**

> It is unspecified whether these arrays are distinct provided their
>   elements have the appropriate values.**If the program attempts to
>   modify a string literal of either form, the  behavior is undefined"**

Comment: `String literal stored in read only location`..well, the'res nothing mandatory, it's just UB to attempt any modifications.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't allowed to modify a string constant, and in this case it's causing a runtime error.  You can fix it by changing the declaration of `str2` to:

```
char str2[] = "Hello";
```

This makes it an array, rather than a pointer to a string constant.

Answer (score 2):

You are not allowed to modify the memory pointed to by `char*` variables initialized with string literals.  It is read-only.

Comment: What? With this wording, it's wrong.

Comment: It's very legal to write something like `char *p = "test", p = "test again";`

Comment: Edited.  Yes, it was incorrect with that wording.  The pointer can be reassigned, but the memory pointed to after assigning a string literal is read-only.